# Error: Cannot find module '…/webpack' Vue js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

`npm run build` throwing error. Where is the problem?

Used

```
npm install --save-dev webpack

npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server
```

I'ts not working, any idea?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete `node_modules` directory and then run `npm install` and then try tu use `npm run build` let me know if it works

Comment: i deleted node mudles and run npm install then npm run build , didnt work

Comment: Include also the package-lock.json

Answer (score -1):

Just do this.. if you want to clean up the webpack package entirely from Vue

```
Delete the node_modules

Delete the package-lock.json

npm install

npm run build
```